# Can't get jQuery .attr() to work with ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I've built a single page app with a nice parallax feature and want to animate the scrolling within the page so it moves nice and slow with in-page links. I have reactJS onClick working, but can't get jQuery's .attr() to work, or any other way to differentiate between links. I also am trying to figure out how to use React to scroll the page to specific points. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var Header = React.createClass({
       onClick: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         console.log('Location' + e.target.value);
           $div = $(this.getDOMNode());
          console.log($div);
          var value = $(this).attr('ref');
          console.log(value);
       },
      render: function() {
        return(
          <div className="header nav-header">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-    toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false" href='#links'>
                     <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>   
                     <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a className="navbar-brand" href="#contents">
                  <img alt="TH" src='img/headshot.jpg' className='headshot img-circle' />
                </a>
                </div>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
                  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#" data-url='hello' onClick={this.onClick}     value='hello' ref='target'>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"  onClick={this.onClick} >Projects</a></li>
                 </ul>
               <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="mailto:#?Subject=from    ">Email Me</a></li>
                <li><a target='_blank' href="#">GitHub</a></li>
                <li><a target='_blank' href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/#">LinkedIn</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is a non-DOM attribute, like `on*` and most user-defined attributes. It is not rendered into HTML, hence can not be accessed by DOM libraries like jQuery (You can try inspecting the DOM in DevTools to see it is not present).

One way you could do what you want is to bind more arguments to the event handler, for example:

```
var Header = React.createClass({
  onClick: function(target, e){
    console.log(target, e);
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <li><a href="#" data-url='hello' onClick={this.onClick.bind(null, 'target')} value='hello'>About</a></li>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: `onClick = (target, e) => {   console.log(target, e);    };`